# How to set width and height auto when rotated image?

Tags: android

When i capture photo in portrait mode, it is landscaped and I use this function to rotate image

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(String mCurrentPhotoPath, String rotationAngle){
    //Set hardCode size imageView 300dp
    int targetW = CommonUtils.ConvertDpTPpx(mContext, 300);
    int targetH = CommonUtils.ConvertDpTPpx(mContext, 300);
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(Float.parseFloat(rotationAngle), (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, photoW/2, photoH/2, matrix, true);
}
```

When  I build on device on S4, it runs right, but when it run on Sony Docomo (SO-04E) and LG LTE2, after capture photo and app crash. A bug is x + width (image) < bitmap.width. And then i edit photoW/4 and photoH/4 so Sony and LG run right but S4 image is cropped. So, at the return line, how i should fix the width and height to run right on all device.